# How are left-right assigner GUI controls called?

Tags: angularjs, user-interface

I'm tasked to implement what I call a left-right assigner GUI control in angularJS.

```
!-----------------------!                 !----------------------!
!Item A                 !       >>        ! Item B               !
!Item C                 !       >         !                      !
!Item D                 !       <<        !                      !
!Item E                 !       <         !                      !
!-----------------------!                 !----------------------!
```

I perfectly know how to do this. But I'm wondering whether something like this exists already. Unfortunately I don't know how this kind of controls are really called, so my googling wasn't really successful.

What's the correct term for this kind of control? Or just point me directly to an angular module :-).

Comment: This is a kind of select widget, check [this blog post](http://blog.boxelderweb.com/2013/08/22/angularjs-multi-select-widget/)